# RadioButtonList.Selectedvalue returns an empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, autopostback

I define the datasource in my c# code and I have a submit button which takes the value of the radiobuttonlist

```
asp:RadioButtonList    ID="RadioPaidIdList" runat="server" DataValueField ="Label" DataTextField = "Label"
```

First time i click submit it returns an empty value. And next time i select a radiolist and click submit it returns a proper value. 
Weird !!

Comment: I guess you are talking about WebForms. When are you adding the values to the radiobuttonlist? OnInit, OnLoad or OnPreRender. Make sure you add them before the events get triggered and that's OnInit or OnLoad if you do it OnPreRender is too late.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a default radio button selected in your form. The code in WPF and winforms is checked="true".

Answer (score 0):

```
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;


 RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
```

apply any one of tow......
i hope it help you........